# Doctrine ODM returns proxy object for base class instead of sub-classed document

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, odm

During my work on providing new functionality to my project, I decided to expand models. I decided to use base class, grouping common methods, with few sub-classes, all kept in a single collection.

Base, abstract class:

```
/**
* @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="EntryRepository")
* @MongoDB\MappedSuperclass
* @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
* @MongoDB\DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
* @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({"entry"="Application_Model_Entry", "image"="Application_Model_Image", "movie"="Application_Model_Movie"})
*/
abstract class Application_Model_Entry
{
    abstract function foo();
}
```

Some concrete class (I have few more of them, similar, but some are abstract):

```
<?php
/** @MongoDB\Document */
class Application_Model_Image extends Application_Model_Entry
{
    function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

After that transition, I opened my index page, and an error was presented - PHP was trying to call an abstract method, as the object returned by Doctrine was a proxy of the **base** class. I thought it was because I renamed the collection from `Application_Model_Image` to `Application_Model_Entry` and internal object references (`$ref` field of `DBRef`) were still pointing to `Application_Model_Image`, but I noticed something funny: **always** first query result was a proper document of a concrete class, and the rest were base class proxies - after I removed the first object from the database, the second one became fine.

On a single-object-showing page everything works fine, for all objects, so I thought maybe it's something with Zend Framework's pager class iterating over results, so I skipped the pager and dumped the objects directly from query. I printed out classes of 100 first results, and some of them had proper classes ([Snippet of that list on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PePjnwPq)). I looked into the DB, but I noticed nothing special about the data ([working](http://pastebin.com/2gy4nqdd) vs [not working](http://pastebin.com/TT0g3zx1)). I thought maybe it's something wrong with the references, but as I wrote above, the same object could become working if it was first on the result list.

Any ideas or hints? I can debug more, but I need to be told where to look inside Doctrine's code.

Comment: The `Document` annotation should not be used in conjunction with `MappedSuperclass`. The former is for concrete implementations, and the latter is for abstract classes. I don't understand the bit about query results beyond the first being proxy objects, as proxies should only get created as placeholders in the context of ReferenceOne/Many relationships.

Comment: The query results were just like I've shown in a first pastebin link - first one is a concrete class, most of the rest are proxies (ProjectProxy\__CG__\Application_Model_Entry to be specific). After removing ``Document`` annotation, everything seems to work fine, thank you very much.

Currently it's not the case, but if I wanted, can I still indicate the collection name for the whole inheritance tree?

Comment: I don't believe `MappedSuperclass` supports any options, so you'll have to experiment. All inheriting classes should still be stored in the same collection per the single-collection inheritance mapping, but the name itself may end up being derived from the abstract class' name.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. Before refactoring I had a custom repository class, and I wanted to be still able to use it, but as ``MappedSuperclass`` accepts no arguments, it was impossbile. I've seen that you suggested a change that could allow inheritance but then you backed down from that. My rationale is that while I could indicate the repository class for all final classes, I can't get a repository object representing the whole inheritance tree (when calling getRepository I have to provide a class, and I can't use the base class), only concrete class with repoclass defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per comment by jmikola above, I've removed `Document` annotation, and everything started to work smoothly. The strange results I had led me to look for an error in a wrong place, but thankfully I got a tip here.

For posterity:

- `Document` annotation is for concrete classes
- `MappedSuperclass` annotation is for abstract classes
- If you receive proxy class objects in query results, it's possible you have a mixup in that department
- You can indicate discriminator field/values even without `Document` annotation.