# Doctrine ODM bi-direction reference with inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, bidirectional

I have this problem: I have several documents that extend some base document. All of these documents have sort of note feature meaning that users can add notes to them. I thus have Note document that is stored in separate collection (it needs to be searchable and cannot be embedded) and have owner property that references the document the note belongs to. I have trouble modelling this with doctrine:

```
<?php

/** @ODM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class Base {
    /** @ODM\Id */
    public $id;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Note", mappedBy="owner") */
    public $notes;
}


/** @ODM\Document */
class MyDocument extends Base {
    /** @ODM\String */
    public $name;
}


/** @ODM\Document */
class Note {
    /** @ODM\Id */
    public $id;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Base", inversedBy="notes") */
    public $owner;

    /** @ODM\String */
    public $text;
}

$mdoc = new MyDocument;
$note = new Note;

$mdoc->name = 'foo';
$note->text = 'bar';

$mdoc->notes[] = $note;
$note->owner = $mdoc;

$dm->persist($mdoc);
$dm->persist($note);

$dm->flush();   

$dm->clear();

$note2 = $dm->find(Note::class, $note->id);
echo $note2->owner->name;
```

And I get the: Notice: Undefined property: Proxies__CG__\Base::$name. In other instances I got: The "Proxies__CG__\Base" document with identifier "XXX" could not be found.

It obviously tries to load the Base class instead of MyDocument. How to force it to load the correct class? I tried setting the Base as MappedSuperclass, setting discriminator field, omitting targetDocument etc. And nothing works as expected and ends with different errors/wrong behaviors.

Is this even possible?

Possibly related:

- [Weird Doctrine ODM exception when using references together with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496987/weird-doctrine-odm-exception-when-using-references-together-with-inheritance)
- https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/442

Note: none of them helped really or I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a discriminator definition for the base class:

```
/**
 * @ODM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ODM\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorField("type")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "document"=MyDocument::class
 * })
 */
abstract class Base {
    // ...
}
```

Once you have that, it should work as expected. Note that the inheritance type can also be `SINGLE_COLLECTION`, depending on whether you want to store the documents in the same or in different collections.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just the note: The minimal required part is the DiscriminatorField (I thought id had some default value). The inheritance type can be omitted (Collection per class is default) and discriminator map as well (saves the classes name)

Comment: Ah, careful there. Inheritance type is "none" by default. You might not notice it in development, but metadata caches leave out discriminator fields unless you set an inheritance type. With the next bugfix release, this will be fixed (see PR [#1556](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1556) for details). Until then, please set an inheritance type to save yourself trouble in production.